# Can't make JDBC connection to MySQL (using Java, IntelliJ, and Linux)

Tags: java, mysql, linux, jdbc, jar

I am having issues trying to get a database connection using the code below:

```
  try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.put("user", user_name);
        p.put("password", password);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/jsp_test", p);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        // handle any errors
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
        return false;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

The error message that is outputted is:

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java
>   -Didea.launcher.port=7532 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/usr/bin/idea/bin
>   -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/about.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/home/bedtimes/Java
>   Projects/db_demo/out/production/db_demo:/opt/java/jre/lib/ext/mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar:/usr/bin/idea/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain
>   Main
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to
>   the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The
>   driver has not received any packets
>   from the server.  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2214)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:781)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:352)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:284)
>     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:620)
>     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:169)
>     at
>   database.Database.connect(Database.java:80)
>     at Main.main(Main.java:13)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:110)
>   Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to
>   the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The
>   driver has not received any packets
>   from the server.  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:343)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2137)
>     ... 18 more Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused   at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:310)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:176)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:163)
>     at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:384)
>     at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:542)
>     at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:492)
>     at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:389)
>     at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:232)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:253)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:292)
>     ... 19 more SQLException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to
>   the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The
>   driver has not received any packets
>   from the server. SQLState: 08S01
>   VendorError: 0
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

I've, literally, no idea how to troubleshoot this error message. The database exists. The username and password exists. I've currently not added any tables to the database but I don't think that can be the issue, since I'm only making a connection after all...

I can provide extra information if needs be. I feel like I've tried a lot. Does anybody know any ways of getting further information on how and why it's failing?

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Can you connect to it directly (using mysql client)? The only useful bit of the traceback is `08S01` and the mysql documentation mentions something about it (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-troubleshooting.html#qandaitem-20-3-5-3-1-3).

Comment: Have you tried using the url "jdbc:mysql://localhost/jsp_test"?  Mostly just a random debug guess.

Comment: I can connect directly using mysql client and my username 'jsp_test'. I still can't connect if I change 127.0.0.1 to localhost.

Thanks for the link, I'll take a look. I'm wondering if somebody else can try doing the same thing with their own machine and mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your connection string, this database should be on the local machine.  Can you try running this command to ensure the socket is open for connections?

telnet 127.0.0.1 3306

and ensure that it connects?  You may not have configured your mysql instance to listen for connections from this machine or on this interface address.  If the connection fails, you need to modify your mysql config, for example:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: [bedtimes@seb ~]$ telnet 127.0.0.1 3306
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

...Looks like you might be right! I'll go and try out that guide and then get back to you if it fixes the issue. C:

Comment: I'm now getting: [bedtimes@seb /]$ telnet localhost 3306
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

...Does anybody know what this means?

Comment: Final fix was by altering hosts.allow as specified on this page: http://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=346836#p346836

Total PITA. Thanks! C:

Answer (score 1):

I had  the same symptoms but for me the solution was to change the bind-address to 0.0.0.0 in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

(Just posting this for others seeking an answer to this question)

Comment: I completely remove the bind-address line and it fixed the same problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this instead:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jsp_test","user_name","password");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try one of the following

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jsp_test","username","password"
```

or

```
"jdbc:mysql://'your machines ip (without quote)':3306/jsp_test","username","password"
```

or

```
"jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/jsp_test","username","password"
```

as a connection string.