# fail to connect to MySQL using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: mysql, database, intellij-idea

I wanted to use Hibernate, so I created a MySQL datasource by database of IntelliJ IDEA. But I got a problem that "connection to MySQL" failed.
I did not change any default setting and just added "demo" as database name.
Here is the description of the problem returned by IntelliJ IDEA.

```
Connection to MySQL - demo@localhost failed.
Communications link failure.
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. 
The driver has not received any packets from the server.
(4s)
```

Sorry but there is no further information about the problem.
I granted IntelliJ IDEA the permission to access Internet since I can download packages via Maven dependencies, so probably there is not any problem with my Internet.

Comment: Can you access MySQL directly from the command line?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how can I access it from the command line? I typed "mysql" in the terminal but the "command could not be found".

Comment: Typing `mysql`, or something like it, will only work if either that command is on your path, _or_ you are in the directory containing the actual executable or script.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what should I do?...

Comment: Have you tried searching SO for answers like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102912/cant-make-jdbc-connection-to-mysql-using-java-intellij-and-linux)?

Comment: Please provide the screenshot of the connection window

Comment: I have actually figured out the problem: it was just I did not open the MySQL server on my laptop. anyway, thanx